# Xamarin Android Mapping Java.Lang.Enum to C# Enum

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

In java I have the enum

```java
package com.acme.common;

// In java world
public enum FooEnum {
    AValue,
    AnotherValue
}
```

This is used throughout the code in Java, e.g.

```java
// In java world
public class Bar {
    void setFoo(FooEnum value) { 
       // ...  
    }
}
```

This is getting mapped to a class in C# which inherits Java.Lang.Enum as follows:

```cs
// Now in C# generated bindings 
// I want this to be a CLR Enum instead
public sealed partial class FooEnum : global::Java.Lang.Enum 
{ 
   // ... 
}   
// C# generated class uses Java.Lang.Enum type for getter and setter
// But I want FooEnum to be clr enum
public partial class Bar 
{        
   public FooEnum Foo { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to map this to a C# enum instead using the [EnumFields.xml,](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata/) but no idea how to.

I googled Xamarin Android EnumFields and found a few results, and have read the [Xamarin Android Binding walthrough](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata/) but still not sure quite how to do this ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have define your Enums in EnumFields.xml how they will appear in C#

```xml
<mapping jni-class="com/acme/common/FooEnum " clr-enum-type="Com.Acme.Common.FooEnum">
    <field jni-name="AValue" clr-name="AValue" value="0" />
    <field jni-name="AnotherValue" clr-name="AnotherValue" value="1" />
</mapping>
```

Then you need to edit EnumMethods.xml for all Methods that consume this Enum

```xml
<mapping jni-class="com/skobbler/ngx/map/realreach/SKRealReachSettings">
    <method jni-name="getFoo" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="Com.Acme.Common.FooEnum" />
    <method jni-name="setFoo" parameter="measurementUnit" clr-enum-type="Com.Acme.Common.FooEnum" />
</mapping>
```

Comment: By jove I think it worked! And I was about to rewrite all the java code to use int instead of an Enum. Thanks!