# Xamarin Android Mapping field Java.Lang.Enum to C# Enum

Tags: c#, xamarin, java-native-interface, java-native-library

I have a problem with converting Java enum to C# enum when binding a Java native library. I have already tried:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata#enumfieldsxml-and-enummethodsxml
- [Xamarin Android Mapping Java.Lang.Enum to C# Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919688/xamarin-android-mapping-java-lang-enum-to-c-sharp-enum)

I have class Receipt and enum Status. Enum Status is nested inside Receipt class(Java code):

```
public class Receipt {

        public enum Status {
        created,
        processing,
        declined,
        approved,
        expired,
        reversed;

    }
    public final Status status; 
}
```

Class Receipt has a field with Status type. When I try to build it with enum mapping it doesn't generate properly. It generates class Status instead of enum(`public sealed partial class Status : global::Java.Lang.Enum)` and what is more important it doesn't generate field status for class Receipt at all(`public final Status status`).

EnumFields.xml

````
<enum-field-mappings>
    <mapping jni-class="com/cloudipsp/android/Status" clr-enum-type="Com.Cloudipsp.Android.Status">
        <field jni-name="created" clr-name="created" value="0" />
        <field jni-name="processing" clr-name="processing" value="1" />
        <field jni-name="declined" clr-name="declined" value="2" />
        <field jni-name="approved" clr-name="approved" value="3" />
        <field jni-name="expired" clr-name="expired" value="4" />
        <field jni-name="reversed" clr-name="reversed" value="5" />
    </mapping>
</enum-field-mappings>```

I would be grateful for any help.
````

Comment: Please add to question whatever `xml` or build instructions you wrote, to tell the mapper what to do. Is there an `EnumFields.xml` for that enum? [I've never done this process; I'm just going by what those links say. Sounds like its up to you to tell the mapper what to do.]

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I've added EnumFields.xml content.

Comment: Hmm. As a test, does it do better if you move enum Status out of Receipt? So isn’t nested.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I was thinking about this option too so I have to modify java code, build .aar file and then rebuild a library. Definitely, I will try. But I was hoping there was any other more straightforward solution to achieve my goal. Thank you for your efforts, I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the topic, but isn't it possible to hand-edit the bindings that are made? The result is a c# file that binds to the java library, right?  What happens if you make a change in that c# file? (Ignore if this makes no sense.)

Comment: It makes sense, but it seems to be not a good practice for two reasons, first - generated C# code invokes Java code so it's pretty tricky to invoke it properly, second - you will have to hand-edit it each time when you are building a library. I have already modified the source Java code and now it works fine.